# Android navigation icon is not vertically aligned when using custom toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin

I have used a custom toolbar class so i can align the title to the right and every thing works fine except the navigation back icon is not vertically aligned

[image]

and this is the custom toolbar class

```
class RTLToolbar @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : Toolbar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {


    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)
        val childCount = childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val view = this.getChildAt(i)
            if (view is TextView) {
                forceTitleCenter(view,l, r)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    private fun forceTitleCenter(view: TextView, l: Int,  r: Int) {
        val top = view.top
        val bottom = view.bottom
        view.layout(l, top, r, bottom)
        navigationIcon?.let{ view.setPadding(it.intrinsicWidth,0,0,0) }
        view.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Toolbar already support RTL natively? https://imgur.com/a/xccVnhs

Comment: it does, but the system language must be one of the RTL Languages and android:supportsRtl has to be true. and i want to force the toolbar to be always RTL @Tenfour04

Answer (score 10):

i found this xml attribute 
`app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"`
 and it did the job, now the back icon is aligned with the title

Comment: after opening around 20 tabs in my browser, finally :) tanks